# IE 10 not rendering Japanese correctly

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I recently discovered an issue with IE10. We have a web page that displays English text beside a translation in Japanese. Some of the Japanese characters display as squares. In the view source page all characters are correctly rendered. The database also has the characters correctly rendered. The unusual part is that when I block the characters with the cursor they convert to the correct characters.

IE10 I believe has a bug.

Anyone having similar issue or know of a fix? Checked all language settings, regional settings, browser font settings and many other tests. Nothing corrects this issue.

Comment: do you have a URL where we can debug the issue? Sounds like it could be an encoding issue. Are you encoding as UTF-8?

Comment: @marc11h Link to your page, or provide a repeatable demo. It is very unlikely that a bug is causing this, and very likely that this is an encoding issue, as dstorey suggested.

Comment: Hello, the page is fully UTF8 compliant. I am sorry I can not provide a link it is in a secured environment. But the issue is repeatable on other IE10 systems, not IE9 or earlier or Firefox. It follows Unicode Standards set from this link...  http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/    I'll try to add an image to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was related to a dual byte character which some fonts and windows applications will support.

Some older fonts may use a two hex character representation to present a single character. Some fonts support this and some do not.

In this case the characters at issue were the following…..

ジ

シ and ゙

The latter two which I think are special characters that combined are intended to represent ジ.

The Unicode Standard from the Unicode ISO web site table defines them like so…..

Decimal Character   HEX Name

12472   ジ   30B8    KATAKANA LETTER ZI

12471   シ   30B7    KATAKANA LETTER SI

12441   っ゙  3099    COMBINING KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK (combined with small tu (っ))

So some fonts use 12471 + 12441 to make 12472. This is what I found. But the actual string has 12471 + 12441 and not 12472 or the hex: 0x30B7, 0x3099 and not 0x30B8.

Any time a font being used does not support this binding, a box is displayed. The challenge is that it may be as simple as someone creating  a birthday card using a non-compliant UTF8 font that could cause a PC to not allow the character to display correctly.